# jsonschema2pojo generating all variable of type object but not the data type i provide

Tags: json, jsonschema2pojo

I am new to this API. Trying to generate a class of 10-15 fields of different data type. But generated class has the 1st variable of the type I declared but remaining if type Object as below.

// Schema

```
{
  "type":"object",
  "properties": {
    "foo": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "bar": {
      "type": "String"
    },
    "baz": {
      "type": "String"
    }
  }
}
```

//Generated Class

```
//...
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"foo",
"bar",
"baz"
})
public class Sample{

@JsonProperty("foo")
private String foo;
@JsonProperty("bar")
private Object bar;
@JsonProperty("baz")
private Object baz;
@JsonIgnore
```

....//

If you notice the 2nd and 3rd variable are declared String but result generated from class is of type object. Can someone help understand what the issue is?

```
{
"type":"object",
"properties": {
    "length": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "width": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "height": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "dimensionalWeight": {
      "type": "string"
    }   
  }
}
```

Comment: `JSON Schema` is case sensitive. Use `string` isntead of `String`

Comment: @Michał Ziober  thank you. I have added another snippet. When i try to generate class file i get "There's a problem: while scanning for the next token (line 15, column 6)". Looks good to me though.

Comment: maybe you mixed something. Updated snippet works properly for me and it is perfectly fine `JSON Schema`